# Running 2 functions at the same time

Tags: discord, rpc

This is an odd case for me.

The following function `rpc_presence` which uses the pypresence library: https://qwertyquerty.github.io/pypresence/html/index.html
uses asyncio.

Here's my code:

```
def stuff():
    print("do stuff")
def rpc_presence():
    while True:  # The presence will stay on as long as the program is running
        RPC.update(details="Great", state=random.choice(quotes), large_image="actual_logo")
        time.sleep(1) 

def main_func():
  rpc_thread = thread.Threading(target=rpc_presence)
  rpc_thread.start()
  stuff_thread = thread.Threading(target=rpc_presence)
  stuff_thread.start()
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\Desktop\Sypherus\Sypherus.py", line 29, in rpc_presence_thread
    RPC = Presence(client_id,pipe=0)
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\presence.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\baseclient.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.update_event_loop(self.get_event_loop())
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\baseclient.py", line 83, in get_event_loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Zylly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.
```

I spoke to the developer and he said he's not much of an asyncio dev nor a threading dev so he can't really help me.
How can I run this function + another function at the same time, while that other function already uses asyncio.
Feel free to look through the source code of the pypresence library, also, I recommend going through the baseclient.py, especially in the get_event_loop() function.